# How to tell if two spherical coordinates lie on the same plane

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, spherical-coordinates

I have the $\rho$, $\theta$, and $\phi$ values of two points, how can one tell that two vectors are normal to the same plane by looking at their spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Any two points lie on some plane through the origin, and on any plane that contains the line between them. So the answer to your original question is "they always lie on some plane."

To answer the question as it's now phrased:

1. Ignore $r$, unless $r = 0$ for one of the points, in which case the normal plane is undefined, so "they don't determine the same plane".
2. Assuming $-\pi/2 \le \phi \le \pi/2$ is the latitude coordinate and $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ is longitude...

The vectors determine the same plane if

1. $|\phi_1| = |\phi_2| = \pi/2$  OR
2. $0 < |\phi_1| < \pi/2, 0 < |\phi_2| < \pi/2$, AND

   a. $\phi_1 = \phi_2$ and $\theta_1 = \theta_2$  OR

   b. $\phi_1 = -\phi_2$ and $\theta_1 = \theta_2 + \pi \bmod 2\pi$. OR
3. $\phi_1 = \phi_2 = 0$ and either

   a. $\theta_1 = \theta_2$  OR

   b. $\theta_1 = \theta_2 + \pi \bmod 2\pi$.

Case 3 is really covered by case 2,  but it's nice to call it out separately.

It seems just possible to me that you really meant to ask the following:

Suppose $C$ is the center of a polar coordinate system, and $P$ and $Q$ are points different from $C$. Then there is a plane $U$ containing $P$ and normal to the vector $P-C$, and a plane $V$ containing $Q$ and normal to $Q - C$. Under what conditions on the polar coordinates of $P$ and $Q$ are the planes $U$ and $V$ identical as planes?

I believe that that question just leads to a horrible mess, and the best answer is "just convert to rectangular coords and write the formulas there."

Comment: We are under the assumption that a plane is parameterized by the normal vector to the point. Each point would specify a plane then right?

Comment: @TrevorHutto Vectors don't  lie in the plane they are normal to. Do you mean that you want to be able to tell when two vectors are normal to the same plane by looking at the spherical coordinates? If so I recommend you edit your question.

Comment: Yes, that is what we mean, I am editing my question...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the coordinates are $(\rho_1,\theta_1,\varphi_1)$ and $(\rho_2,\theta_2,\varphi_2)$ Two vectors are normal to the same plane if and only if they are nonzero multiples of each other. One case when this occurs is when $\theta_1=\theta_2$ and $\varphi_1=\varphi_2$. This takes care of the case where the vectors are positive multiples are each other.

It is also possible that the vectors could be negative multiples of each other. The formulas for $\rho,\theta,\varphi$ in terms of $x,y,z$ are
$$\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$$
$$\varphi=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
If we negate all of $x,y,z$ then $\rho$ and $\varphi$ stay the same, but theta becomes $\pi-\theta$. Hence the two possibilities are
$$\theta_1=\theta_2\mbox{ and }\varphi_1=\varphi_2$$
or
$$\theta_1=\pi-\theta_2\mbox{ and }\varphi_1=\varphi_2$$
As long as $\rho$ is not zero, it is irrelevant to the discussion.

Comment: What about $\phi_1 = \pi/2, \phi_2 = \pi/2, \theta_1 = 0, \theta_2 = \pi/4$? (Some folks might deny that $\theta_2 = \pi/4$ is legitimate, but others wouldn't, so I think one ought to handle that case.)

Comment: @JohnHuges In Cartesian coordinates that yields $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=1$ for the first vector and $x=0$, $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for unit vectors, which don't determine the same plane.

Comment: Apologies for not noticing that what I call $\phi$ is your $\theta$ and vice-versa. In *my* notation,  both vectors point towards the north pole, but they have two different (irrelevant) longitudes.

Comment: @JohnHughes Not being an analyst and not having taught multivariable calculus for two years, I had forgotten the formulas. Rather than trying to figure them out myself, I looked them up on Wikipedia, so I'm using their conventions.

Comment: That's fine. (As I recall, physicists tend to use one, mathematicians the other). But the point is still the same: pick two points at the north pole ($\theta = \pi/2$ in your notation) and two distinct (but not opposite) values of $\phi$. You get the same *vector* (hence same normal plane), but with two different sets of coordinates that don't satisfy your conditions. I suppose the question I answered was "when do two sets of polar coords determine the same normal plane" while you answered "when do the polar coords, determined by these formulas, for two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ determine..."

Comment: @JohnHughes Two different sets of spherical coordinates can't determine the same vector unless that vector is 0. The range of the coordinates is restricted so the representation of any nonzero vector is unique.

Comment: Ah...we differ on this point. In the plane, for instance, I'm happy to admit the polar coordinates $(r, \theta) = (1, 4 \pi)$ for the point with rectangular coordinates $(1, 0)$ (if for no other reason than that it makes discussions of covering spaces easier). To each his own.

Comment: @JohnHughes It's true that if you allow them to they can, but there's no reason to do that in this problem.